# Make an object available in the function to be tested

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, mocha.js

How can i make a object, created in the test module, available in the function to be tested?

For example, the test code gets a DOMParser class from the `xmldom` module:

**test:**

```
import assert from 'assert';
import { DOMParser } from 'xmldom';
import { parseHtml } from './../src/parse-html.es6';

describe('HTML Parser', function () {
    it('Hello World', function () {
        parseHtml();
    });
});
```

That DOMParser class should be the one used in the function being tested:

**parseHtml():**

```
export function parseHtml(html) {
    const parser = new DOMParser();

    return parser.parseFromString(
        `<html><head></head><body>${html}</body></html>`,
        'text/html'
    );
}
```

How do I get that DOMParser class so it is the one `parseHtml` will use?

I will test with `mocha` and `nodejs`.

Comment: What's the question here? You import it?

Comment: The question is, the DOMParser is not available in parseHtml(). How can i make it available in this function? In parseHtml() i use the DOMParser from browser. In the test function, i import the DOMParser from xmldom, to `emulate?` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by restructure the parseHtml function into a class and passing die DOMParser() Object on my test.

**test/parse.js**

```
import chai from 'chai';
import xmldom from 'xmldom';
import Parse from './../src/parse.es6';

const { assert } = chai;
const { DOMParser } = xmldom;

let parse;

describe('Parser', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        parse = new Parse(DOMParser);
    });

    it('should parse HTML', function () {
        let html = parse.html('');

        assert.ok(html);
    });
});
```

**parse.es6**

```
export default class Parse {
    constructor (domparser) {
        // This hack is needed for testing. To emulte the browsers DOMParser.
        this.domparser = !domparser ? new DOMParser() : new domparser();
    }

    html(body) {
        return this.domparser.parseFromString(
            `<html><head></head><body>${body}</body></html>`,
            'text/html'
        );
    }
}
```

Also got the benefit to better extend the parser. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`sinon`](http://sinonjs.org/) to spy or stub `xmldom` classes:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import { parseHtml } from './../src/parse-html.es6';
import { default as xmldom } from 'xmldom';

// Spy on the xmldom.DOMParser() constructor
var spy = sinon.spy(xmldom, 'DOMParser');

describe('HTML Parser', function () {
  it('Hello World', function () {
    parseHtml();
    // Check if the constructor was called once (and only once)
    assert(spy.calledOnce);
  });
});
```

Before every test, make sure to reset the spy (`spy.reset()`).

Comment: Yes, you're right. In this case it will work. But i need the result of ```parse.html();```. I need a real parsed html.

Comment: @danbruegge it's not clear to me what exactly it is you want to test.

Comment: In other tests i have a html snippet that has to be put into this html and should be parsed.

Comment: @danbruegge so `parseHtml()` is basically a utility function for your Mocha tests? In that case, just import `xmldom.DOMParser()` in `parse-html.es6` to make it a valid module and you're done.

Comment: No not like that. ```parseHtml()``` is a function used in production on the browser.

Comment: @danbruegge ahh right, now it's all starting to make sense... :-)